# Simple animation problem by importing CSV file (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, route, animation, timemanager

I am new to QGIS. I want to create an animation to of point moving from one coordinates towards other. The problem is that the points appear when I load .csv but does not appear when simulation played using time manger.

The problem I decode was that maybe my date format is incorrect in QGIS. It lead me to a confusion as in my CSV I had the correct format. Can anyone explain why is QGIS converting the time format on its own and why am I not allowed to create a time format of my own.

Screenshots are attached for reference.
[image]

Comment: As far as I can see from your screenshot (1st one), the field is correctly defined as `date` type, so it should be correctly recognized. If you right click the resulting layer and go to properties > Temporal tab and activate `Dynamic temporal control`: can you set configuration to `Single Field with Date/Time` and choose the imported field? Please also provide more information about the settings made for temporal control. Otherwise, it's difficult to help

Comment: Thank you so much for offering help @Babel . The following are the temporal control and errors whenever I try running it using time manager: https://snipboard.io/xXtlUS.jpg

Comment: OK, so the import of the date field worked, it is recognized as a temporal field. Why are you using time manager plugin instead of built in temporal control, available in newer QGIS versions? I would stick to temporal control. By the way: when you post screenshots, just post one by one, not two or three together in one image file, that makes it harder to read.

Comment: It is always a good idea to share your data (at least a simplified version of it) for testing, otherwise people willing to help have to reconstruct everything from scratch.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I'm still learning, surely I'll take your advices and beware in future. And thank you sir for your help, temporal layer is working. Actually, the next step is to achieve this functionality using PYQGIS and I have no idea where to begin. Can you please guide me on that?

Comment: OK, for PyQGIS I would advice to post another question as in fact it is a different question then this one. The policy of this site is to ask just one question per post, see [tour].

Comment: Thank you very much for letting me know the policy, however just came across a post that said "We use a Focused question/Best answer model -- we're more of a problem-solving site that a tutorial one, so coding questions without code are likely to be closed. If you provide a code sample of what you have tried, and report how it didn't work for you, you're more likely to get a response than by requesting general coding assistance." by Vince. So I'll just search upon and build up a basic code before posting. Thankyou for your help man, really appreciate it.