# How to add delay and not cause the program to lag. I currently tried using time.sleep but it causes program to crash

Tags: pyqgis, point, animation

I'm new to PyQGIS. I want to create points and update the location after 5 seconds and the code for that is given below. The issue I'm having is that during 5 seconds the script becomes unresponsive and I'm not able to visualize the transition (point location being changed). The transition however is occurring as observed in the results. If I add multiple points, I can only visualize the last point.

What could I be doing wrong?

Python Code

```
import time
from threading import Event
from qgis.core import QgsDistanceArea
layer = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=EPSG:4326', 'point', 'memory') 
provider = layer.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([QgsField('Name', QVariant.String)])
provider.addAttributes([QgsField('ID', QVariant.Int)])
layer.updateFields() 
f = QgsFeature()
p1 = QgsPointXY(62.32, 25.13)
p2 = QgsPointXY(72.83, 33.56)
p3 = QgsPointXY(74.41, 31.52)
f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(p1))
f.setAttributes(['Gwadar Airport',1])
provider.addFeature(f)
f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(p2))
f.setAttributes(['Islamabad Airport',2])
provider.addFeature(f)
f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(p3))
f.setAttributes(['Allama Iqbal International Airport (Lahore)',3])
provider.addFeature(f)
layer.updateExtents() 
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
def shiftPoints():
  res=layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures([1])
  f=QgsFeature()
  p1=QgsPointXY(68.32,28.13)
  f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(p1))
  f.setAttributes(['New Airport',1])
  provider.addFeature(f)
  layer.updateExtents() 
  QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

QTimer.singleShot(2000, shiftPoints)
```

Comment: Related : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201137/animating-objects-on-canvas-to-change-color-by-delay-using-pyqgis

Comment: Thank you for your referral. I tried reproducing the code published by that post using PyQGIS. It shows no output for me. Can you guide me on where I could find the exported canvas as it does not appear in the QGIS interface?

Comment: You may also want to look into [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QTimer.html) and in particular the `singleShot()` method. It would probably require reorganising the code after your sleep into a function, however.

Comment: Thank you very much @Matt I have tried using your suggestion and it had been working well for me. My modified code is updated. The challenge now is that the updated location refreshes only when I press on the screen.

Comment: Try adding `iface.mapCanvas().refresh()` at the end of the `shiftPoints()` function, or after the call to the timer.

Comment: I belive you edited your **question** to include the proposed solution. It is important to leave code in your question that reproduces your original problem, else the question becomes confusing/meaningless to other readers.

Comment: I'm sorry for that action. I'll act upon your piece of advice in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Following on from your [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/447244/simple-animation-problem-by-importing-csv-file-qgis), there are a few ways to animate points on the map canvas using pyqgis.

Firstly, using your .csv file with a timestamp field as an example, you can load it as a delimited text layer, set some temporal properties, and create an animation using the [QgsTemporalNavigationObject](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsTemporalNavigationObject.html) class with the following code:

```py
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
project = QgsProject.instance()

uri = r'file:///C:/Users/HP/Desktop/CENTAIC/AnimationTesting/rectangular-coords-for-practice.csv?delimiter={}&crs=epsg:4326&xField={}&yField={}'.format(',', 'lon', 'lat')
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri,'practice_coords','delimitedtext')
if lyr.isValid():
    project.addMapLayer(lyr)
    iface.zoomToActiveLayer()

t_props = lyr.temporalProperties()
t_props.setMode(Qgis.VectorTemporalMode.FeatureDateTimeInstantFromField)
t_props.setLimitMode(Qgis.VectorTemporalLimitMode.IncludeBeginExcludeEnd)
t_props.setStartField("time")
t_props.setFixedDuration(1.0)
t_props.setDurationUnits(QgsUnitTypes.TemporalDays)
t_props.setIsActive(True)

tc = canvas.temporalController()
tc.setNavigationMode(QgsTemporalNavigationObject.Animated)
t_extent = QgsTemporalUtils.calculateTemporalRangeForProject(project)

# Or create your own QgsDateTimeRange object...
#all_times = [f['time'] for f in lyr.getFeatures()]
#t_extent = QgsDateTimeRange(QDateTime(all_times[0]), QDateTime(all_times[-1]).addDays(1), True, True)

tc.setTemporalExtents(t_extent)
interval = QgsInterval()
interval.setDays(1.0)
tc.setFrameDuration(interval)
tc.setFramesPerSecond(1.0)
tc.rewindToStart()
tc.playForward()
```

The result should be something like:

[image]

Another option, without using a temporal layer, instead starting with some airport coordinates and names, is to use a memory layer and a `QTimer` to change geometry and attribute values in a timed sequence.

```py
class showAirports(object):

    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.airports = {'Gwadar Airport': QgsPointXY(62.32, 25.13),
                        'Islamabad Airport': QgsPointXY(72.83, 33.56),
                        'Allama Iqbal International Airport (Lahore)': QgsPointXY(74.41, 31.52),
                        'Faisalabad International Airport': QgsPointXY(72.98, 31.36),
                        'Quetta International Airport': QgsPointXY(66.94, 30.24),
                        'Bacha Khan International Airport' : QgsPointXY(71.52, 33.99),
                        'Benazir Bhutto International Airport': QgsPointXY(73.1, 30.2),
                        'Multan Airport': QgsPointXY(71.42, 30.2)}
                
        self.layer = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=EPSG:4326', 'Airports', 'memory')
        self.layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField('Name', QVariant.String)])
        self.layer.updateFields()
        self.f = QgsFeature(self.layer.fields())
        self.f.setAttributes([list(self.airports.keys())[0]])
        self.f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry().fromPointXY(list(self.airports.values())[0]))
        self.layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([self.f])
        
        # Set up labeling for temporary layer
        self.settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
        self.txt_format = QgsTextFormat()
        self.txt_format.setFont(QFont('Arial', 10))
        self.txt_format.setColor(QColor('black'))
        self.buffer_settings = QgsTextBufferSettings()
        self.buffer_settings.setColor(QColor('White'))
        self.buffer_settings.setSizeUnit(QgsUnitTypes.RenderMillimeters)
        self.buffer_settings.setSize(1.0)
        self.buffer_settings.setEnabled(True)
        self.txt_format.setBuffer(self.buffer_settings)
        self.settings.setFormat(self.txt_format)
        self.settings.fieldName = 'Name'
        self.settings.drawLabels = True
        self.labels = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(self.settings)
        self.layer.setLabeling(self.labels)
        self.layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
        self.layer.triggerRepaint()
        self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
        
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(self.layer)
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)# Change to 5000 for 5 second interval
        self.i = 1
        self.stop = 7
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.show_airport)
        
    def start(self):
        self.timer.start()
        
    def clean_up(self):
        self.timer.stop()
        print('Timer stopped')
            
    def show_airport(self):
        self.layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({1: {self.layer.fields().lookupField('Name'): list(self.airports.keys())[self.i]}})
        self.layer.dataProvider().changeGeometryValues({1: QgsGeometry().fromPointXY(list(self.airports.values())[self.i])})
        self.layer.triggerRepaint()
        self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
        if self.i == self.stop:
            self.clean_up()
        self.i+=1
            
x = showAirports(iface)
x.start()
```

Result:

[image]

Finally, to simply animate some markers on the canvas, without creating a vector layer, you could also use the [QgsVertexMarker](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVertexMarker.html) class.

There is some more info on rubber bands and vertex markers in the [pyqgis developer cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/canvas.html#rubber-bands-and-vertex-markers).

Example:

```py
class vertex_marker_animation(object):
    
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
        self.project = QgsProject.instance()
        self.project.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('epsg:4326'))
        self.marker = None
        self.count = 0
        self.lat = 25.5
        self.lon = 66.5
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.test)
                
    def start(self):
        self.timer.start()
        
    def test(self):
        if self.marker:
            self.canvas.scene().removeItem(self.marker)
        self.marker = QgsVertexMarker(self.canvas)
        self.marker.setColor(QColor(255,0,0))
        self.marker.setIconSize(10)
        self.marker.setIconType(QgsVertexMarker.ICON_CROSS)
        self.marker.setPenWidth(3)
        self.marker.setCenter(QgsPointXY(self.lon, self.lat))
        ###########################################################
        if self.count == 10:
            self.clean_up()
        self.lat+=0.5
        self.lon+=0.5
        self.count+=1
            
    def clean_up(self):
        self.timer.stop()
        if self.marker:
            self.canvas.scene().removeItem(self.marker)
            self.marker = None
    
        
x = vertex_marker_animation(iface)
x.start()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: wow ! one of your best answers this year for sure !

Comment: @Taras, thank you! It means a lot. I feel bad that I have not been in contact with you. Es tut mir sehr leid! I hope you had a great Christmas and I wish you a safe and happy new year. I will try to reach you by email soon.

Comment: Danke! Frohe Weihnachten! Please do it ^_^

Answer (score 2):

The repaint command helped me update the point itself. The working code is given below which allowed me to create points and update point location after 2 seconds automatically.

```
import time
from threading import Event
from qgis.core import QgsDistanceArea
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
layer = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=EPSG:4326', 'point', 'memory') 
provider = layer.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([QgsField('Name', QVariant.String)])
provider.addAttributes([QgsField('ID', QVariant.Int)])
layer.updateFields() 
f = QgsFeature()
p1 = QgsPointXY(62.32, 25.13)
p2 = QgsPointXY(72.83, 33.56)
p3 = QgsPointXY(74.41, 31.52)
f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(p1))
f.setAttributes(['Gwadar Airport',1])
provider.addFeature(f)
f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(p2))
f.setAttributes(['Islamabad Airport',2])
provider.addFeature(f)
f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(p3))
f.setAttributes(['Allama Iqbal International Airport (Lahore)',3])
provider.addFeature(f)
layer.updateExtents() 
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
def shiftPoints():
    res = layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures([1])
    f = QgsFeature()
    p1 = QgsPointXY(68.32, 28.13)
    f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(p1))
    f.setAttributes(['New Airport',1])
    provider.addFeature(f)
    layer.updateExtents()
    layer.updateFeature(f)
    layer.commitChanges()
    layer.triggerRepaint()
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
QTimer.singleShot(2000, shiftPoints)
```

A big thanks to @Matt and @Taras for guidance.